# Using libgdx and socket IO gottox

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets

Currently I am using Libgdx and Socket IO client to make a simple multiplayer game. Right now i am able to use node.js socket io to communicate with each app. The problem is when i get the message onMessage it does not draw the batch texture correctly. Here is my code in for socket io in libgdx.

```
public void runIO(){

    try {
        socket = new SocketIO("sdfsdfsdfsdf");
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("test4");
                System.out.print(data);
            }
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JsonElement json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("test3");
                System.out.println("Server said:" + json.getAsJsonObject().get("msg"));
                changeEmpty("test");
            }
            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, JsonElement... args) {
                System.out.println(event);
                System.out.println(args[0].getAsJsonObject().get("msg"));
                changeEmpty("test");

            }
            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arg0.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("testststests");
            }

        });
        //socket.emit("test", cardImg);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void changeEmpty(String imgString) {
    emptyImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cards/2_of_diamonds.png"));
    game.batch.begin();

    game.batch.draw(emptyImage,400,240);
    game.batch.end();
}
```